# In returned event object from Google Event api, there is meeting room in the location

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-people-api

I'd like to double check of Google Event Object.
I've tried [this API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get), and the return was like below.

```
{ 
   "kind":"calendar#event",
   "etag":"\"3159500823012000\"",
   "id":"xxx",
   "status":"confirmed",
   "htmlLink":"https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=xxx",
   "created":"2020-01-23T03:30:46.000Z",
   "updated":"2020-01-23T03:33:31.506Z",
   "summary":"meetingroom",
   "location":"Tokyo Tower, 4-chōme-2-8 Shibakōen, Minato City, Tōkyō-to 105-0011, Japan, 会議室B (test) (6), 会議室A (test) (4)",
   "creator":{ 
      "email":"jungmo.kang@xxxxx.com",
      "self":true
   },
...
}
```

and view on Google calendar is like this
[image]

There are meeting rooms in location property, is this correct behavior?
then, could you let me know how can I get location without meeting rooms please?

Comment: the location is returned in your response i dont understand the question can you please clerify what the issue is.

Comment: I put the address as location which is `Tokyo Tower, 4-chōme-2-8 Shibakōen, Minato City, Tōkyō-to 105-0011, Japan`. but, in returned json, location's value is `Tokyo Tower, 4-chōme-2-8 Shibakōen, Minato City, Tōkyō-to 105-0011, Japan, 会議室B (test) (6), 会議室A (test) (4)`. 会議室B (test) (6) or 会議室A (test) (4) are meeting room's name that I added as meeting room.

Comment: The rooms are part of the location, it is not configurable. The only possibility is to remove them cropping the String with code.

Comment: OK Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For documentation purposes,

As per @Jescanellas comment, the rooms are part of the location, it is not configurable. The only possibility is to remove them cropping the String with code.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: BTW, Meeting is resource. and "projector" or "car" or anything can be "Resource" not only meeting room. If I put any of resources in Calendar event, there'd be same resource in "Location". I don't understand this. Because "projector" is not location.